# Windows Phone Database in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a database application in windows phone. I want to access the database stored in the device(or in emulator) in visual studio or any other explorer. For example, after deploying application on emulator and performing CRUD operation on emulator(or device) , I want to see the data of the database in server explorer or any other explorer. Is it possible? If Yes, can you provide a solution for it.? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating your database as a file in isolated storage then you can easily use [Windows Phone Powers Tools](http://wptools.codeplex.com/) to copy the file off the development phone / emulator and on to your PC for opening using whatever utility you'd like.

You can also use the Windows Phone Power Tools to copy a modified file back to the phone / emulator if you desire also.

Something I've done myself while testing my SQLite database for my own app.

Comment: Thank you. It removed the blocker

Comment: Is it possible to connect to database file using connection string or by any other method?